# JavaRDD.map(f -> {...}); code got skipped

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. My code got an unexpected behavior. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
            // Compute results
            JavaRDD<Result> resultJavaRDD = inputRdd.map(f -> {
                // this code block is skipped
                System.out.println("computation starts");
                ......

                // call computation method
                ResultGenerator resultGenerator = new ResultGenerator();
                Result result = resultGenerator.run();
                return result;
            });

            // Persist results
            resultJavaRDD.cache();      // result directly jumped here
            JavaRDD<Integer> returnedIds = resultJavaRDD.map( r -> persistResult(r));
            returnedIds.cache();
            returnedIds.collect();
```

The behavior is that the code block inside the `inputRdd.map(f->{});` was skipped and it directly hit `resultJavaRdd.cache()` line.
However, if I do something below

```
resultJavaRDD.repartition.collect();
```

The code block won't be skipped. Can anyone explain why, please?

Comment: `map` is a transformation and that is lazy. Before you call some action, it will not transform.

Answer (score 0):

Since the map function of rdd is a transformation and so it is lazy function. Once you call any action, then it will be also called but if there is no action then it will not.

See the rdd basics from the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

Comment: thanks for replying. Could you be more specific to my case, please?